# Webpack 5 build disables all onclicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am making a small React app with minimal React modules using Webpack 5 as the bundler. I am having an issue with my build files.
If the build files are not deferred in the index.html, everything is working fine. AKA my development files are fine. After running the build, all my events (onClick, onMouseOver, etc.) no longer work.
I have a warning saying that the build size is too large but it doesnt explain the events that are no longer functioning.
One of them is:

```
<div className='connectDiv'>
  <button className='btnConnect'
    onMouseOver={() => btnText('mouseOver')}
    onMouseOut={() => btnText('mouseOut')}
    onClick={() => aircallAPIping()}
    style={btnStyle}>
    {buttonText}
  </button>
</div>
```

With the function being:

```
function btnText(action) {
    if(buttonText === 'Connected' && action === 'mouseOver') {
      setText('Disconnect');
      setStyle({backgroundColor:'orange',color:'white'});
    };     
    if(buttonText === 'Disconnect' && action === 'mouseOut') {
      setText('Connected');
      setStyle({backgroundColor:'green',color:'white'});
    };
    if(buttonText === 'Not Connected' && action == 'mouseOver') {
      setText('Connect');
      setStyle({backgroundColor:'orange',color:'white'});
    };
    if(buttonText === 'Connect' && action == 'mouseOut') {
      setText('Not Connected');
      setStyle({backgroundColor:'white',color:'#74787d'});
    };
  };
```

I have a App.js AND a main.js file in the `src` folder. Does that collide with each other?

My webpack configuration is:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: [ "@babel/polyfill", path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main.js')],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' }
      ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, require.resolve('./public/index.html')],       
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]'
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

Does anyone have/had the same issue? And what can be done about it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please may you be more specific? Do you get any errors? What about putting `console.log` in the event props to make sure?

Comment: Why are you emitting build files into the same folder when your HTML template file is in the `public` folder? It will add multiple script tags for the same `bundle.js` on every emit. What is the use?

Comment: Hey @evolutionxbox, thanks a lot for helping. I tried adding console.logs in the events but no logs show up and the buttons dont react to any click or mouse over anymore.

Comment: Hey @MORÈ, thanks a lot for your help. There is no use for it, I didnt change the webpack config file and took it over as is. How would you recommend setting up the build files, in a separate build folder?